# firebase massages error- this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: xcode, swift, firebase, key, chat

Я создаю приложение в котором присутствуют сообщения. Я сообщения создал через firebase, и все работало почти норм, пока не вышла эта ошибка.

Я пробывал удалять user , messages , user-messages - данные из firebase, а потом выходить из аккаунта и создавать новый. Но это не помогло.

Раньше у меня тоже самое было, но ошибка заключалась в том что в User() не присутствовали нуждающиеся данные, там 
connected...
которым я присваивал значения из firebase. Но щас все есть и не понимаю почему ругается.
Можете пожалуйста сказать в чем проблема и как ее можно решить.

Раньше в user записывались данные id : ... и еще ... как показано на последней фото. С течением времени прибавилось кол. данных, которые записать нужно. Одно с другим норм. все работало.

```
**Ошибка:** 2017-02-24 15:38:41.437 Wimp General[4630:838440]  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:*** this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 65.***'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2485391b 0x23feee17 0x24853629 0x24fc71f3 0x2504aa03 0x1906b8 0xff04c 0x2bc9db 0x2e042f 0x1777b7f 0x1777b6b 0x177c655 0x24815b6d 0x24814067 0x24763229 0x24763015 0x25d53ac9 0x28e37189 0xec354 0x2440b873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

[image: Ошибка]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E20QD.png)

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMsFV.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что там в этом dictionary? можете в вопрос добавить?

Comment: Я добавил все данные, которые могут пригодиться.  Я сам думаю, что дело в данных, которые записаны в users, только не знаю как удалить все данные одновременно, но не удалять саму модель users.

Comment: Я удалил все данные из users, user-massage, massage  щас, но ничего не поменялось к сожалению.

Comment: как вы уже наверно поняли, крэш у вас из за этого "65". не могу точно сказать, что там к чему. надо подумать

Comment: Я щас закоментировал эту часть и вывел значения user.id. Вышло очень много значении, я не знаю от куда они взялись если я их уже удалил

Comment: Щас опять вывел значения, и вышло только одно, что и должно быть так. Этот firebase странный ...

Comment: Щас у меня все работает. Я не знаю в чем была пролема, но ответ на вопрос это удалите все данные и ждите.

Comment: я думаю через несколько дней все повторится :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что экземпляр класса User не поддерживает NSKeyValueCoding протокол.